# SQL trigger to insert data from one table to another if a condition is met

Tags: sql, triggers

I am miserably failing to build a sql trigger (in background) where I want to insert data from one table to another if a certain condition is met, something like this:

1. Create trigger on table `Invoice`
2. If `inv_number` starts with `inv`
3. Then `Insert into Document (var1,var2,var3) values (inv_number, inv_date, inv_amount)`

Thanks

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely. Also, please post the **table structure** for the two tables involved - `Invoice` and `Document`

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **SQL Server** (as I said in comments - triggers are **highly** vendor-specific, so if you're using something else, you'll have to adapt as needed), you can use something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgInvoiceInsert
ON dbo.Invoice
AFTER INSERT    -- adapt if you need to run this after UPDATE or DELETE, too
AS 
BEGIN
    /* In SQL Server, if you inserting a bunch of rows 
       at once using an `INSERT INTO .... SELECT ....` 
       approach, then this trigger will be called only *ONCE*, 
       with all the inserted rows in the "Inserted" pseudo table.
       Handle it accordingly - in a set-based manner
    */
    INSERT INTO dbo.Document (col1, col2, col3)
        SELECT i.inv_number, i.inv_date, i.inv_amount)
        FROM Inserted i
        WHERE i.inv_number LIKE 'inv%'
END
```

For further details, check out the [official Microsoft documentation on SQL Server triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)